True or False? Minimum of a convex function on a ball is the point on the ball closest to the minimizer
I am wondering whether this is true or false, since I can't seem to find any counterexamples.
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex and has a minimizer $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$. Let $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the closed ball of radius $r$ around $\mathbf{x}$, denoted $B_r(\mathbf{x})$. Then $f$ is minimized at the point on the boundary of $B_r(\mathbf{x})$ closest to $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$. (Of course, we assume $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$ is not in the ball itself.)
It seems intuitive, but I can't seem to use convexity nicely. Nor have I found any counterexamples yet. Any suggestions?

Try
$F : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
F(x,y) = (x-3/2)^2+5(y-1)^2 .
$$
Of course $F$ is convex on $\mathbb R^2$ with minimum value $0$ achieved at
the point $C =(3/2,1)$.
Below we graph the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the ellipse $F(x,y) = 1$.

The minimum of $F$ on the unit circle is approximately $1$, at the point $A$.  But the point of the circle nearest to $C$ is $B$.  $F(B)$ is much larger than $F(A)$.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
